# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit) screen fades out while booting

Tags: touchscreen, alsa, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I've installed the official 7" touch screen on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I used the Raspberry Pi Imager to put Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit) on a SD card and while booting, the screen fades out to a black screen (backlight still on, so vertical stripes are visible).

After enabling SSH access, I found this in my syslog:

```
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.922202] hdmi-audio-codec hdmi-audio-codec.1723.auto: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_set_jack on hdmi-audio-codec.1723.auto: -95
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.952923] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.953464] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.953621] rc rc0: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.953758] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input1724
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.968667] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi kernel: [  280.968852] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f806000.vec (ops vc4_vec_ops [vc4])
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[167]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
Nov 17 15:29:45 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[159]: event0: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```

I've also created a SD card with Ubuntu and it's working correctly, so it's doesn't look like a hardware failure.

How can I fix this problem?

edit: I've tried to install `raspios_full_armhf-2021-05-28` and it's working fine.

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323414a which is further discussed on github https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4686